# NSMutableArray addObject: does not work

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am new to **objective-C**, and I am trying to add objects to a instance `NSMutableArray` variable. Somehow the objects (item) can be passed into the `setSubItems` method, but the array `_subItems` always returns "`nil`".

Here is the **header file**:

```
@interface SUKContainer : SUKItem
{
    NSMutableArray *_subItems;
}
-(void)setSubItems:(id)object;
@end
```

**implementation**:

```
@implementation SUKContainer
-(void)setSubItems:(id)object 
{      
    [_subItems addObject:object];
}
@end
```

**main**:

```
SUKContainer *items = [[SUKContainer alloc] init];      
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    SUKItem *item = [SUKItem randomItem];
    [items setSubItems:item];
}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Maybe you should actually create the array object.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to the following code

```
@interface SUKContainer : SUKItem

// The ivar will be created for you
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *subItems;

// I'd change the name to addSubItem as it makes more sense 
// because you aren't setting subItems you're adding a subItem
-(void)addSubItem:(id)object;
@end

@implementation SUKContainer 

 // No need for a synthesize as one will auto generate in the background    

- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) { 
        // Initialize subItems
        self.subItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)addSubItem:(id)object 
{     
    if (_subItems == nil) {
        // If the array hasn't been initilized then do so now 
        // this would be a fail safe I would probably initialize 
        // in the init.
        _subItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } 

    // Add our object to the array
    [_subItems addObject:object];
}

@end
```

Then somewhere else in your code you can do

```
SUKContainer *items = [[SUKContainer alloc] init];      
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    SUKItem *item = [SUKItem randomItem];
    [items setSubItems:item];
}
```

To be honest though you could probably just do the below and it looks cleaner then having another method called `addSubItem:`

```
SUKContainer *items = [[SUKContainer alloc] init];

// If subItems hasn't been initialized add the below line
// items.subItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     [items.subItems addObject:[SUKItem randomItem]];
}
```

Comment: I thought [[SUKContainer alloc] init] would initialise SUKContainer instance variable as well, no? And Thank you so much. it works!!

Comment: Only if you have written your `init` method yourself otherwise it will just call super. Added a simple init method to the code

Comment: But if you use the items.subItems, won't the dot notation call the setSubItems method by default?

Comment: No if you did `[items.subItems setSubItems:[SUKItem randomItem]];` then it will call the `setSubItems:` if you do `[items.subItems addObject:[SUKItem randomItem]];` it will call the `addObject:` method.